# How to insert linear regression residual plots in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, linear-regression

"unused argument(model),I am creating residual plots of linear regression model in shiny app but it does not showing any output.so can anybody please tell me whats wrong in this code?"

```
 ui <- navbarPage(tabPanel("Predictions",
               tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Linear Regression",tags$h1("Predicting G3 using 
      G1 as predictor using Linear Regression"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("ML"),plotOutput("Model")
            ))
    ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
           model <- lm(formula=G3 ~ G1,data=students)
              output$ML <- renderPrint({
                  summary(model)
                     })
            output$Model <- renderPlot({plot(model)
  })


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it (re-using your code with `mtcars` dataset) :

```
library(shiny)
library(lmtest)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)

ui <- navbarPage(tabPanel("Predictions",
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Linear Regression", 
                                     tags$h1("Predicting G3 using G1 as predictor using Linear Regression"), 
                                     verbatimTextOutput("ML"),
                                     plotOutput("Model")
                            ))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  model <- lm(formula = wt ~ hp, data = mtcars)

  output$ML <- renderPrint({
    summary(model)
  })

  output$Model <- renderPlot({
    tmp <- augment(model)
    ggplot(tmp, aes(x = .fitted, y = .resid)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = loess, formula = y ~ x) 
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, I should warn you that I don't really know the utility of `augment` because I found this function while searching for a solution for a similar problem. I believe this isn't a great way to learn so if somebody can tell me what it is used to do, please do because I didn't really understand the documentation.